# How to parse a function with ply in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, lex, ply

Im trying to parse a custom programming language using PLY in python, and im a bit confused

so for example, i want to parse

```
on create:
  modifyProp relative width => 11
  modifyProp height => 14
```

i want to make the `on` part work like `def` and then read the next part as an input (in this case `create`, and then parse the `:` like in python

i also want to make the `modifyProp` part in the same way, with `relative` being read as a parameter instead of an input if its included, and then reading `=>` as a "change this to" command, then reading the integer

sorry if thats a bit confusing, any resources i could find were too confusing and i wasnt able to figure this out on my own, thanks in advanced if you can help

Comment: So you want `modifyProp` as a function within `create` function? What do you want `create` to do besides call `modifyProp`?

Comment: @OriYarden basically, and i just want to be able to nest things within it, modifyProp was just an example mainly

Comment: I recommend that you learn about grammars and create one for your language.

Comment: @Labbo Lab where do these lines of code come from? A file? Is it in string?

Comment: @OriYarden a file, although im currently testing with just strings

Comment: Implementing languages is typically the subject of a semester-long class. You're not going to get an answer in a SO question.

Comment: Get yourself a copy of the dragon book and study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want:

```
on create:
  modifyProp relative width => 11
  modifyProp height => 14
```

as `str`ing and formatted in Python:

```
some_code_in_string = '''
def create(relative):
    def modifyProp(relative):
        return True if relative[0] >= 11 and relative[1] >= 14 else False
    return modifyProp(relative)
print(create(relative))
'''
```

so that we can `exec`ute `some_code_in_string`:

```
exec(some_code_in_string, {'relative': [15, 20]})
```

Outputs:

```
True
```

Now if we have `a` few lines of that code already in `str`ing (which you might already have as a file), we can do something like:

```
def pythonicize(some_string):
    some_new_string = ''
    func_end = some_string.find(':')
    func_start = True
    index = func_end - 1
    while not some_string[index:func_end].__contains__(' '):
        index -= 1
    func_start = index
    some_new_string += 'def'
    some_new_string += some_string[func_start:func_end]
    some_new_string += '(relative):'
    some_new_string += '\n'
    some_new_string += '...'
    return some_new_string

a = '''
on create:
  modifyProp relative width => 11
  modifyProp height => 14
'''
b = pythonicize(a)
print(b)
```

Outputs:

```
def create(relative):
...
```

I'm not really familiar with PLY language, I just got you started so you can finish writing the `pythonicize` function as you see fit; there may be many edge cases (which I'm unfamiliar with) that you'd have to account for.